# Problema diseñando mi clave primaria en una tabla en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, jpa

No estoy seguro de como crear mi tabla. En concreto con respecto a las claves primarias.

Necesito una tabla con 3 campos que formen la clave primaria. Quiero usar JPA y por este motivo me obliga a tener un campo ID. Así que este sería mi modelo.

MY_TABLE
**ID**, INT, AUTO_INCREMENT
**YEAR**, CHAR(4)
**MONTH**, CHAR(2)
**COD_HOUSE**, CHAR(6)
**FIELD_1**, INT
**FIELD_2**, INT
**FIELD_3**, INT

Quiero que mi clave primaria sea:
PK (YEAR, MONTH, COD_HOUSE)

En SQL Server 2005, tengo esto modelo funcionando, pero en MySQL cuanto trato de crearlo, se queja, me obliga a tener ID como clave.

El problema que veo es que cuando peristo este objeto, me creará un ID, por ejemplo:

(2016, 10, 111001, 10, 10, 10), crea el ID=1

Si por alguna razón se intenta guardar de nuevo, me creará un ID=2, pero con los mismo valores.
(2016, 10, 111001, 10, 10, 10), crea ID=2, y tendré los ID diferentes pero la clave que necesito duplicada.

El campo ID lo necesito porque es con el que relaciono una tabla anexa

Alguna idea o sugerencia?
Gracias.

IN ENGLISH

I'm not sure how to create my table. In particular with my keys.

I need a table with 3 field for my primary key. I want to use JPA and for this reason **I have** to add and ID field. So, this is my model.

MY_TABLE
**ID**, INT, AUTO_INCREMENT
**YEAR**, CHAR(4)
**MONTH**, CHAR(2)
**COD_HOUSE**, CHAR(6)
**FIELD_1**, INT
**FIELD_2**, INT
**FIELD_3**, INT

I want my Primary Key as:
PK (YEAR, MONTH, COD_HOUSE)

In SQL Server 2005, I have this model working, but in MySQL when I try to create it, it complain.

The problem as I see is, when I persist and object it will create and ID, for example:

(2016, 10, 111001, 10, 10, 10), it create ID=1

If for some reason I try to create the same key
(2016, 10, 111001, 10, 10, 10), it create ID=2, but I will have a duplicate PRIMARY KEY

I need the ID field because it related with another table.

Any idea or suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Bienvenido a es.stackoverflow en español, intenta traducir está pregunta o ve a stackoverflow en el lugar adecuado.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque pertenece a StackOverflow en Ingles

Comment: Tienes razón, ciérrala. Me ha mandado directamente a la versión en español en lugar de a la versión inglesa como hasta ahora. Gracias por tu paciencia.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero poner `ID` como primaria y `(YEAR, MONTH, COD_HOUSE)` como otra clave única.

El índice único, tal como lo indica su nombre, es un índice cuyos valores deben ser únicos (no repetirse) en la tabla. A diferencia de un indice normal, te proporciona seguridad y mayor velocidad si los valores de un campo o de una combinación de campos se espera que sean únicos.

En este caso, haciendo el índice único compuesto por los tres campos, la combinación `YEAR`-`MONTH`-`COD_HOUSE` solo podrá existir una vez y estarás utilizando la clave más eficiente para ello.

Tiene exactamente el mismo funcionamiento que la clave primaria.

Mi sugerencia era para diferenciar el identificador de la fila, el ID, ya que no puedes prescindir de él ni *deberías* hacerlo, del índice compuesto `YEAR, MONTH, COD_HOUSE` que necesitas para hacer tus consultas y por consistencia, que es solo un índice y no *debería* ser tu clave primaria. Es más que nada una cuestión de usos.

Comment: Hola @Gabriel. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías incluir un ejemplo de cómo se definiría según lo que estás diciendo para responder a la pregunta?

Comment: Hola. No tengo claro la diferencia en id primaria y clave unica

Comment: Agregué algunos comentarios.